# Label offsetting with multiple labels in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I have written the following code to draw the diagram of an RLC circuit:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}\draw
(0,2) node[anchor=east] {1} to [short,*-] (0,2)
to[R,R=$R$] (4,2) node[anchor=west] {2} to [short,*-] (4,2)
to[L,L=$L$,i>=$i_{L}$] (4,0)
to[short,-*] (2,0) node[rground] {G} to [short] (0,0)
(0,0) to[C,C=$C$,mirror,v=$v_{C}$] (0,2)
;\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the following result:

[image: RLC Circuit with clashing labels - on the capacitor, and also G.]

My settings are:

```
\usepackage[siunitx,americanvoltages,americancurrents,americanports,cuteinductors,fulldiodes,arrowmos,smartlabels]{circuitikz}
```

How do I fix it (offset the voltage label leftwards and center offset the G label)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For the "G" placement, you can use the `label` key.
2. For the C component labels, `mirror` seems to mess label positioning, so you can use some `xscale` and manual shifting (first and two diagrams below), or to use `yscale=-1` (third diagram below).

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx,americanvoltages,americancurrents,americanports,cuteinductors,fulldiodes,arrowmos,smartlabels]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
(0,2) node[anchor=east] {1} to [short,*-] (0,2)
to[R,R=$R$] (4,2) node[anchor=west] {2} to [short,*-] (4,2)
to[L,L=$L$,i>=$i_{L}$] (4,0)
to[short,-*] (2,0) node[rground,label=$G$] {} to [short] (0,0)
(0,0) to[C,C=$C$,xscale=3,mirror,v={$\hspace*{-12pt}v_{C}$}] (0,2)
;\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
(0,2) node[anchor=east] {1} to [short,*-] (0,2)
to[R,R=$R$] (4,2) node[anchor=west] {2} to [short,*-] (4,2)
to[L,L=$L$,i>=$i_{L}$] (4,0)
to[short,-*] (2,0) node[rground,label={120:$G$}] {} to [short] (0,0)
(0,0) to[C,C=$C$,xscale=3,mirror,v={$\hspace*{-12pt}v_{C}$}] (0,2)
;\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
  (0,2) node[anchor=east] {1} to [short,*-] (0,2)
  to[R,R=$R$] (4,2) node[anchor=west] {2} to [short,*-] (4,2)
  to[L,L=$L$,i>=$i_{L}$] (4,0)
  to[short,-*] (2,0) node[rground,label={120:$G$}] {} to [short] (0,0)
  (0,0) to[C,C=$C$,v={$v_{C}$},yscale=-1] (0,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How do I retain the +/- signs on $v_{C}$ and offset this label leftwards, so that it does not run into the circuit as it is in my original question?

Comment: @user2751530 Which + - signs? I don't see them.

Comment: In my posted image. They are smashed into the wire (the -'s).

Comment: @user2751530 Please see my updated answer. I'm still confused about the + and - signs.

Comment: @user2751530 How come they appear in your image but not in mine? Do you have any special setting for the components?

Comment: Please see updated post for configuration details.

Comment: @user2751530 Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Mystery why the package does not take care of multiple labels automatically. The use case I presented is a very common one.

Comment: @user2751530 The problem is the `mirror` option. I updated my answer with another possible solution without manual shiftings that could be of interest for you.